# Where can I get some real time data for testing my storm program?

Tags: real-time, apache-storm

Recently I am learning Storm and doing some practice. But some confusions happens to me. In the example Storm gives us, the Spouts are all generate some string randomly. Can I get some open source real-time data on the Internet?

Answer (score 0):

You can check many social networks. Quick googling shows that Twitter has a [Public Stream](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/streams/public). Properly [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/public_feed/) and Google+ offer something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the Twitter firehose and process messages in real-time.